# Cant get password hash via openssl in c same format as crypt, mkpasswd or openssl via cmdline

Tags: c, openssl, password-encryption, password-hash

I need to create a hashed password via the openssl lib in C. Unfortunately, I'm not able to get the expected result

This is the code I`m using:

```
unsigned char hash[SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];
SHA256_CTX sha256;
SHA256_Init(&sha256);
SHA256_Update(&sha256, "xxx", 3);
SHA256_Update(&sha256, "11111111", 8);
SHA256_Final(hash, &sha256);

for(int i = 0; i < SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
{
    printf("%02x", hash[i]);
}
```

The output will be

> 57b2e9dd7f27e02ce026c1a40c7685b4658c2dff55e3a9de93186e545d1c4af1

but i expected

> EDgBhRzUlXHcobBLtDfoWalyRFoSMnO1/q.s10aKSY7

since this is the output the crypt lib will produce as well as mkpasswd or openssl via shell.

See:

```
mkpasswd -m sha-256 --salt=11111111 xxx
$5$11111111$EDgBhRzUlXHcobBLtDfoWalyRFoSMnO1/q.s10aKSY7
```

or

```
openssl passwd -5 -salt 11111111 xxx
$5$11111111$EDgBhRzUlXHcobBLtDfoWalyRFoSMnO1/q.s10aKSY7
```

or

```
printf("%s\n", crypt("xxx", "$5$11111111"));
// also prints $5$11111111$EDgBhRzUlXHcobBLtDfoWalyRFoSMnO1/q.s10aKSY7
```

I need to get this  working with the openssl lib. 
Am I completely wrong with creating the hash and salt, or is this just a dump formatting issue?

Comment: swapping those 2 lines will result in `0bec54ee4f82261f2817b32b46002dd01e8f4bf75f6f3665bdf1e756c2b3e5ac` which is also not the desired output... the only I was able to get the same output as my c-snipped was via http://www.convertstring.com/de/Hash/SHA256 (exact same hash). So I think it really is about the formatting afterwards... but cant think of anything else then printing hex .... (some snippets from stackoverflow print it the same way)

Comment: Also see: https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/SHA-crypt.txt for a description of the password algorithm. It's more than just hashing a string once with sha256.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm is not just a simple SHA256 hash.

As reference the OpenSSL implementation can be found on [github](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/apps/passwd.c) (shacrypt(...)).

Comment: so there is no "simple" way to do this via the openssl library rather then implementing the algorithm "yourself" ?

Comment: there are likely other libraries to do this in c, but i don't know any.

Comment: Finally managed to port that function. Compared to glibc, this is relatively easy